# What should be used as User id?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Flask-login required me to provide the following callback:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
```

But what should be used as id? Can I just use username? If yes, what should I return in case of user_loader("admin").is_authenticated()? How do I know if he was authenticated in the previous session? Should I keep track of it manually?

Comment: For your first question.  The library does not "*Restrict you to using usernames and passwords, OpenIDs, or any other method of authenticating.*",  for your second question, it should return a boolean value depending on if that ID is authenticated. Not really sure what else you mean by asking that.

Comment: As for knowing if authenticated in a previous session, yes you'll need to store it because sessions end when you close the page. There is a [remember me](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#remember-me) setting

Answer (score 0):

user_id is from User model, add the following code under User model:

```
class User(db.Model):

    '''

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

Another easier way is to inherit from UserMixin:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    ...
```

Find the reference doc from [here](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class)

Answer (score -1):

using

```
class User:
    def get_id(self):
        return id(self)
```

should guarantee that two `User` objects only return the same id when they are the same Object.

Comment: When should I use is_authenticated then? Why can't it be just `return True`